# lower/upper bound in the integral test for convergence of series

Tags: calculus, integration, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

In the integral test for the convergence of series,

for example,
because $\sum_{j=1}^n \frac{1}{j} \gt \int_1^{n+1} \frac{1}{x} \,dx $, and $\lim_{n\to \infty}  \int_1^{n+1} \frac{1}{x} \,dx= \infty$, the sum diverges.

In another example, because $\sum_{j=1}^n \frac{1}{j^2} \lt \int_1^{n} \frac{1}{x^2} \,dx$ and $\lim_{n\to \infty} \sum_{j=1}^n \frac{1}{j^2} \lt 1+ \sum_{j=1}^\infty \frac{1}{x^2} = 2$, the sum converges.

But how do we know the integral is an upper or lower bound? For me, it seems that the equation of the integral could come to both the right or left side of the intervals.
For example, in the new sum $\sum_{j=1}^\infty \frac{1}{\sqrt[3]j},$ am I right that we don't know that until calculating to know the integral of the term is infinite (thus the integral is indeed a lower bound)?

[first example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bC5ZJ.png)
[second example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t7zSS.png)

Comment: $\int_k^{k+1}\frac  1 x dx <\frac   1k$ and $\int_k^{k+1}\frac  1 x dx >\frac 1 {k+1}$. Sum over $k$.